# Writing to a file inside if statement not working in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, file-writing

I've looked around here a bit and found similar questions but not exactly. If there is one, I apologize and please point me to it.

I have the following code. I'm trying to create a csv file of simply an ID pulled from a filename and the filename itself. This is the ENTIRE script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find( \&findAllFiles, '.');
exit;

sub findAllFiles {

my @fp1;
my @fp2;
my $patId;
my $filename;
my $testvar = "hello again";


$filename = $File::Find::name;

if ($filename =~ /\.pdf$/) {
open (my $fh, '>', 'filenames.csv') or die "Failed to open - $!\n";
print $fh "starting...$testvar\n" or die "Failed to print to file - $!\n";
    @fp1 = split('/', $filename);
    @fp2 = split('_', $fp1[-1]);
    $patId = $fp2[-1];
    $patId =~ s/\.pdf$//;
    print "Adding $patId, file = $filename\n";
    print $fh "$patId,$filename\n" or die "File print error: $!";
close $fh or warn "close failed! - $!";
}


return;
}
```

The line that prints to the screen, prints perfectly.
If I take the file open/close and the first print statement out of the `if` block, it prints that line into the file, but not the data inside the block.
I've tried every combo I can think of and it doesn't work. I've alternated between `'>'` and `'>>'` since it clearly needs the append since it's looping over filenames, but neither works inside the `if` block.

Even this code above doesn't throw the `die` errors! It just ignores those lines! I'm figuring there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow what is your problem ("it doesn't work" isn't a very good description), but does `find( { wanted => \&findAllFiles, no_chdir => 1}, '.');` instead of your `find( \&findAllFiles, '.');` (and `>>` instead of `>`) solve it?

Comment: You never actually print the value of `$File::Find::name` or `$filename`. So my first guess would be that your filenames don't match your regex.

Comment: 1) I actually DO print out the $filename and it prints to the screen exactly correctly.
2) @Dada - it worked! I have no clue what that snippet means, but it did it! Thanks!

Comment: note that filenames.csv will be created in the directory where the pdf is found, since find() changes directories as it searches; is that what you want?

Comment: is the "Adding ..." message showing up?

Comment: @ysth - yes. and thanks for the other tip - that's what was happening! I'm reminded of the movie the Illusionist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [`File::Find::find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html#*find*)'s documentation:

> Additionally, for each directory found, it will chdir() into that directory

It means that when you `open` inside `findAllFiles`, you are potentially opening a file `filenames.csv` inside a subdirectory of your initial directory. You can run something like `find . -name filenames.csv` from your terminal, and you'll see plenty of `filenames.csv`. You can change this behavior by passing `no_chdir` option to `find`:

```
find( { wanted => \&findAllFiles, no_chdir => 1}, '.');
```

(and additionally changing `>` for `>>` in your open)

However, personally, I'd avoid repeatedly opening and closing `filenames.csv` when you could open it just once before calling `find`. If you don't want to have your filehandle globally defined, you can always pass it as an argument to `findAllFiles`:

```
{ 
    open my $fh, '>', 'filenames.csv' or die "Failed to open 'filenames.csv': $!";
    find(sub { findAllFiles($fh) }, '.')
}

sub findAllFiles {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

filenames.csv will be created in the directory where the pdf is found, since find() changes directories as it searches.  If that's not what you want, use an absolute path to open it (or open it before calling find, which seems like a better idea).